# How to change the background color of "...Would Like To Access Your Photos" dialog pop-up?

Tags: ios, swift

I apologize, this may seem like an obvious solution, but I cannot figure it out.

I am using a `UIImagePickerController` to take pictures or select pictures from the photo gallery.

The first time my app is loaded and the app needs access to the photo library, the App Name "Would Like To Access Your Photos" dialog pops up.

Currently, the background color is black like so:

[image]

How exactly do I change the background color from black to white (or some other color)?

I'm not exactly sure what view this is part of. I tried to do the following which resulted in nothing:

```
picker.cameraOverlayView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

How can I gain access to that view's background color to change it?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the view hierarchy where the picker is shown?

Comment: @ShamasS: apologize, I'm not sure what you mean?...do you mean this?...NavControl1->VC1->NavControl2->VC2 (where the picker is shown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to access the `view` property of a `UIImagePickerController` object and then setting the `view`'s `backgroundColor` to your custom choice like so:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
picker.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score -3):

I think the space is `CFBundleDisplayName`. You try change name your application's `Info.plist` file contains a key: `CFBundleDisplayName` with not empty string value.

Comment: how is this relevant to my question?

Comment: You should've placed this as a comment instead of an answer Son Thanh